# Use enableWaterLock

Tags: watchos-4

I want to use the new "enableWaterLock" feature in my watchOS app, but I can't make it work.

Here's my code:

```
@IBAction func lockScreen() {
    if #available(watchOSApplicationExtension 4.0, *) {
        WKExtension.shared().enableWaterLock()
    }
}
```

lockScreen() is called from a menu button, that is added in the willActivate() function, if all criteria for the feature are met.

```
    //Screen Lock
    if #available(watchOSApplicationExtension 4.0, *) {
        if WKInterfaceDevice.current().waterResistanceRating == .wr50 {
            addMenuItem(with:.block, title: "Lock Screen", action: #selector(lockScreen))
        }
    }
```

In the documentation is says:

> The following rules apply when using Water Lock:
>
> - You can only enable Water Lock when the app is running in the foreground during an active workout or location session.
> - The app must be running on a supported device (the WKInterfaceDevice object's waterResistanceRating property must be set
>     to wr50).
> - Water Lock remains active until the user unlocks it. You cannot programmatically unlock the watch.

So I guess my watch app is not and active workout or location session. 
What's needed to be one of these two?
My app uses locationManager, but that's apparently not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a HKWorkoutSession object

```
let workoutConfiguration = HKWorkoutConfiguration()
workoutConfiguration.activityType = HKWorkoutActivityType.swimming
workoutConfiguration.swimmingLocationType = HKWorkoutSwimmingLocationType.pool
workoutConfiguration.lapLength = HKQuantity(unit: .yard(), doubleValue: 25)

do {
    var workoutSession = try HKWorkoutSession(configuration: workoutConfiguration)
    workoutSession?.delegate = self         
    healthStore.start(workoutSession!)
} catch {
    // ...
}
```

You can [watch the Apple example from WWDC at 6:23](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/221/) to see Apple's full example of creating a workout session and enabling water lock.

Comment: I still can't make it work...
I've added your code to the "function lockScreen()".
In the WorkoutSession didChangeTo delegate function, I've added the enableWaterLock() call, if the toState is running.
I've also added some text color changes so I can debug that the functions are called, and all seems fine - but the water lock isn't activated, even though the function is called.

Comment: I played around with the DigitalCrown delegate and suddenly it started working. I don't know exactly what I did, and even after removing the code again, it stil works.Thanks!

Comment: It would be nice if there was a way to catch when the waterLock was disabled again.